# Getting ABI Version Mismatch initializing LibVPX Encoder

Tags: swift, objective-c++, vp8, libvpx

I am getting an error code 3 after calling vpx_codec_enc_init_ver; which appears to be a version mismatch issue. I have deleted libvpx from my machine, and recompiled using the iOS build script several times. At this point I am not sure what is causing the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Steps to build:

1. `git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/webm/webmdshow`
2. `cd libvpx`
3. `./configure (with options)`
4. `cd ..`
5. `mkdir build`
6. `../libvpx/build/make/iosbuild.sh`
   Use vpx framework that is generated.

Initializing the encoder in Xcode :

```cpp
import VPX

let encResult = vpx_codec_enc_init_ver(&codec, vpx_codec_vp8_cx(), nil, 0, 2)
print(encResult)
```

output:

```
Printing description of encResult:
▿ vpx_codec_err_t
  - rawValue : 3
```